# need to extract key from properties file

Tags: java

see i have one PROPERTIES File now i have to write a program for extraction of all keys from that file

```
    1000012001    = Title
    1000012002    = Status
    1000012003    = Start Date
    1000012004    = End Date
    1000012005    = Date
    1000012006    = Name
    1000012007    = Description
    1000012008    = Sr No
    1000012009    = Action
    1000012010    = Add
    1000012011    = COMPASS Alerts
    1000012012    = All
    1000012013    = Apply
```

like in given example i have to extract keys like 100012001---100012013 from that file keys may not be in one sequence and keys need to store in **hashmap** or **arraylist**

so please help me

Comment: If your question is just how to extract the `numbers` in the file and store it in a `HashMap` just use a `BufferedReader` along with a `FileReader` and `Tokenize` the input and store the first `token` of every line in a `HashMap`

Comment: it is key=value                                                      i have to extract only keys.    in given example key is number and value is string but there may be possibility that value is also number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in); // create input stream for your file.
// from now you have Properties object with your data.
// since properties extends Hashtable the task is done.
// if you still need keys in list, say
List<Object> keys = new ArrayList<Object>(props.keySet());
```

I hope this helps although the question does not seem very clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.Properties which extends Hashtable.

```
Properties props=new java.util.Properties();

props.load(inputStream);
```